# How do I add to the list table a filter?

Tags: plugins, wp-admin

I am trying to find the hook for adding a filter to the list under "Posts [Add New]":

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `views_edit-post` hook to do so. It is a possible variation of [`views_{$this->screen->id}`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L257) and resides in [class-wp-list-table.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php).

```
add_filter('views_edit-post', 'my_post_views' );
function my_post_views( $views ){
    $views['html_class_name_for_li'] = 'the html'; // ex: <a href="#">something (11)</a>
    return $views;
}
```